# XCode removes watchOS2 App when running iPhone target

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

I have a problem, every time I run my iPhone target the Watch App gets uninstalled and I have to manually install it again via the companion App. The device log says: "The system does not trust application". I've seen the "Trust this computer" dialog once on the Watch and I tapped trust. Is there any way to re-trust? Thanks